# Own strncpy() C++

Tags: c++, arrays, strncpy

I am trying to implement my own version of strncpy(), i found a source code from this [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13040/c-like-cpp-code-to-do-strncpy-and-copy-a-string-to-a-buffer-which-is-not-long-en).

But I encountered a `Unhandled exception at 0x00411ad5 in exercise 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00417800.` everytime the code reaches this code `while((x++ < n) && (*dest++  = *source++));`

Here is the complete code:

```
char *strncpy(char * destination, const char * source, size_t n){
        char *dest;
        dest = destination;

        size_t x=0;
        while((x++ < n) && (*dest++  = *source++)); //this is where unhandled exception occurs
        while(x++ < n){
            *dest++ = 0;
        }

        return dest;
    }

int main(){
    char *sample = "blue";
    char * sample2 = "red";

    cout << strncpy(sample, sample2, 5);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me why this occurs and how should I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot overwrite the memory reserved for a literal.

Comment: The error occurs, because you write to a read-only string, `sample`.

Comment: And didn't you mean to return `destination` instead of the `dest`, which has advanced past the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your destination is `"blue"` which is a string literal, that is a constant. As such it is located in a read-only part of memory (and pointed at by local `sample` variable), thus error when writing.

Try this:

```
int main(){
    char sample[] = "blue";
    char * sample2 = "red";

    cout << strncpy(sample, sample2, 5);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

which makes `sample` an array in local, writeable memory.

Comment: thanks, the exception is solved. but the output is something weird. it didn't copy what is inside sample2, it gives out weird symbols. -> SOLVED, had mistaken in the return, should've returned the destination instead of the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write to a string constant (`sample`); write to a `char` array instead:

```
int main(){
    char *sample = "blue";
    char buffer[5];

    cout << strncpy(buffer, sample, sizeof(buffer));
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, it was already explained to you that you can't overwrite a string that is defined like that.
Second, you cant use cout << strncpy if that function returns pointer to the end of the copied string.

Comment: *"cant use `cout << strncpy` if that function returns pointer to the end of the copied string"* - but it doesn't - it returns a pointer to the start of the destination buffer, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy).

Comment: do you realize we talk about the code from the question? and that code returns dest that was incremented, not destination

Comment: True that the question's code does do that now, but given the aim to code *"my own version of strncpy()"* - until it returns `dest` it's still buggy, and once it's fixed to return `dest` `cout` will start working.  Good insight though that there's that extra bug in the existing implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with your program 
The first one is that function `strncpy` has to return `destination` instead of `dest`

```
char *strncpy(char * destination, const char * source, size_t n){
        char *dest;
        dest = destination;

        size_t x=0;
        while((x++ < n) && (*dest++  = *source++)); //this is where unhandled exception occurs
        while(x++ < n){
            *dest++ = 0;
        }

//        return dest;
        return destination;
    }
```

The second one is that string literals are immutable. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour.

Thus main function should be rewritten the following way

```
int main(){
    char sample[] = "blue";
    char * sample2 = "red";

    cout << strncpy(sample, sample2, sizeof( sample ) );

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Also it is a bad style of programming to use variable with name `x` as a count. It is better to use for example `i`.

I would write the function simpler

```
char * strncpy( char *destination, const char *source, size_t n )
{
        char *dest = destination;

        while ( n-- && ( *dest++  = *source++ ) );
        while ( n-- ) *dest++ = '\0';

        return destination;
}
```